# Checking invertibility of Discrete-time system

Tags: discrete-signals

I got a question while solving the questions below.

> A system is described by $$y[n]=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{n+1} x[m].$$
> Classify this system as to time invariance, BIBO stability and invertibility.

As far as I know about checking invertibility of system is to check whether system's input and output is a one-on-one correspondence.

But in this question how can I prove they are one-on-one correspondences?

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is a bit of an odd-ball. It appears to be a non-causal integrator and follows the difference equation of

$$y[n] = y[n-1]+x[n+1]$$

It has pole at $z=1$, i.e. it's marginally stable and not BIBO stable.

The inverse can be determined by simply solving for $x[n]$ and we get

$$x[n] = y[n-1] - y[n-2]$$

which is a differentiator with on sample delay. That's a perfectly well behaved function.

Where this counts as "invertible" or not would depend on how exactly you define "invertibility" for a non-causal marginally stable system.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier Transform and Z Transform are always one-to-one.  And any two LTI systems that multiply to be identically 1 for all frequencies on the unit circle are an inverse filter pair.  So, for an inverse filter pair, each filter's transfer function is the reciprocal of the other in the pair.  That means swapping poles and zeros and reciprocating the constant factor in the transfer function.

If you toss in causality as another constraint, that must mean that each LTI filter must have at least as many poles as it has zeros.  If both filters of the inverse filter pair are to be causal, that must mean that the number of zeros must equal the number of poles.

If you toss in strict stability as another constraint, that must mean that each LTI filter must have poles inside the unit circle.  If both filters of the inverse filter pair are to be stable, that must mean that both poles and zeros of each are inside the unit circle.  That means both are **minimum phase filters** as well as stable.

So, if causality and stability are also required, then the number of poles and zeros must be equal and all poles and zeros must have magnitude of less than one (putting them inside the unit circle) and the inverse-filter pair simply swaps the poles and zeros and inverts the constant gain factor.

Comment: $H_1(z)H_2(z)=1$ doesn't necessarily mean that $H_2(z)$ perfectly inverts $H_1(z)$ in the sense that it recovers its input signal. Simple example: $H_1(z)=1-z^{-1}$. In that case any DC component at the input can't be recovered. In general, the same is true for any system with zeros on the unit circle.

Comment: @MattL. how does that happen with a **minimum phase** and **stable** filter?  When do we end up multiplying by zero, which of course irreparably destroys information that cannot be regained in the inverse filter?

Comment: It doesn't, at least not with a strictly minimum phase system. But I was referring to the first paragraph in your answer where you didn't impose any of those constraints yet.